# Trying to create a web scraper for dell drivers using python3 and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a web scraper to grab info about Dell Drivers from their website. Apparently, it uses java on their site to load the data for the drivers to the web page. I am having difficulty getting the driver info from the webpage. this is what I have cobbled together so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import json

resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser', from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
```

So far none of these have worked to try and get the data for the drivers:

```
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='text/preloaded').text)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/x-suppress').text)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='text/javascript').text)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
```

I am not very skilled at python, I have been looking all over trying to cobble something together that works. Any assistance to help me get a little further in my endeavor would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers')

time.sleep(3)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Show all')]").click();

page = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='downloads-table')

results2 = results.find_all(class_='dl-desk-view')
results3 = results.find_all(class_='details-control sorting_1')
results4 = results.find_all(class_='details-control')
results5 = results.find_all(class_='btn-download-lg btn btn-sm no-break text-decoration-none dellmetrics-driverdownloads btn-outline-primary')

for results2, results3, results4, results5 in zip(results2, results3, results4, results5):
   print(results2, results3, results4, results5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers')

time.sleep(3)

page = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html5lib')
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I gave it a try, it looks like I have to setup chrome web driver stuff to get it working. Is there maybe a way of doing it without needing the extra stuff?

Comment: I was able to get it working with some minor changes
--------------------------------------------------------------------
`from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers')

time.sleep(3)

page = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Sushil's answer working  on my machine with some minor changes

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers')

time.sleep(3)

page = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='downloads-table')

results2 = results.find_all(class_='dl-desk-view')
results3 = results.find_all(class_='details-control sorting_1')
results4 = results.find_all(class_='details-control')
results5 = results.find_all(class_='btn-download-lg btn btn-sm no-break text-decoration-none dellmetrics-driverdownloads btn-outline-primary')
```

The problem though is that this still only gets me 10 out of 79 drivers

I need a way to get all of the drivers that are available listed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull the JSON file that has the driver information.  Saves a lot of hassle trying to use a web driver or other tricks.

Example for Dell Precision 7760 with Windows 10:
https://www.dell.com/support/driver/en-us/ips/api/driverlist/fetchdriversbyproduct?productcode=precision-17-7760-laptop&oscode=WT64A
(Note: "productcode" and "oscode" parameters.)

In order for this to work, you must have a request header "X-Requested-With" and set the value to "XMLHttpRequest".  If you do not have this then you will get a "no content" result.

Format the resulting JSON and you should easily see the structure of the results including all of the driver data that you see on the support website.